# Giving options to Start-process in windows powershell when running as Admin

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am trying to run a perl script with admin privileges using a PowerShell script. 
My PowerShell script has the below command:

```
start-process powershell -verb runas "perl script" -RedirectStandardError D:\testscripts\stderror.log -RedirectStandardoutput D:\testscripts\stdopt.log
```

When I run the .ps1 script which has above command within it. I am receiving the below error...

> Start-Process : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified
>   named parameters.

Please suggest me..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```powershell
start-process perl script.pl -RedirectStandardError "D:\testscripts\stderror.log" -RedirectStandardoutput "D:\testscripts\stdopt.log"
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually I am trying to run the command using admin previlages

Comment: Looks like the Start-Process cmdlet has two parameter sets where you cannot define both RedirectStandardoutput and the verb parameter.

Comment: I tried the below. But still receiving the same error                                                                                        start-process perl D:\testscripts\sp.pl -RedirectStandardError "D:\testscripts\stderror.log" -RedirectStandardoutput "D:\testscripts\stdopt.log" -verb runas